# How to loop data inside laravel blade tables?

Tags: laravel, foreach, html-table, laravel-blade

I have this table in laravel blade file.

```
@foreach($items as $item)
<table class="pack-table">
    <tr>
        <th width="30%">Color</th>
        <th width="10%">Pack</th>
        <th width="60%">Total Units</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @foreach($item['grid'] as $color => $sizes)
                {{$color}}<br><br>
            @endforeach
        </td>
        <td>
            @foreach ($item['grid'] as $color => $sizes)
                @foreach ($sizes as $size)
                    {{ $size['description'] }}<br><br>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        </td>
        <td>
            @foreach ($item['grid'] as $color => $sizes)
                @foreach ($sizes as $size)
                    {{ $size['total'] }}<br><br>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
@endforeach
```

This code prints a table as below in the picture.

[image]

This just prints each data. But I want this to be print as below:
For example color, **VELBL** has sizes **MEDIUM, X LARGE, LARGE, X SMALL & SMALL**, and Total Units for all these pack sizes are **0**.

So I need to print all these records first and then print the next color **BLUAS**, it's pack sizes, and the total for each.

How can I modify my code to print as required?

**Update:**
[image]

```
<table class="pack-table">
    <tr>
        <th width="30%">Color</th>
        <th width="10%">Pack</th>
        <th width="60%">Total Units</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($item['grid'] as $color => $sizes)
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="left">{{ $color }}</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($sizes as $size)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $size['description'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $size['total'] }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: You could do better with divs. If you want to do it with <table>, you will have to do sub <table> in your <table> to group data

Comment: can you provide me an example to do with sub tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    <table class="pack-table">
        <tr>
            <th width="30%">Color</th>
            <th width="10%">Pack</th>
            <th width="60%">Total Units</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($item['grid'] as $color => $sizes)
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="left">{{ $color }}</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($sizes as $size)
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{{ $size['description'] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $size['total'] }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </table>
@endforeach
```

Comment: thank you for this answer, but prints the table not as expected, please check my question I've updated with an image

Comment: @user13080158 You forgot to add an empty `td` above `<td> {{$ size ['description']}} </td>`. Therefore, you have a package where the color is. Can you show how it is printed with the option that I sent you? so that from it I can make changes

Comment: thank you very much for this answer, it gave me the exact result which I expected. but the problem was align="left" was not working there, so I added this line there style="text-align:left;" and it now printing as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you're looking for with less loops

```html
@foreach($items as $item)
<table class="pack-table">
    <tr>
        <th width="30%">Color</th>
        <th width="10%">Pack</th>
        <th width="60%">Total Units</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($item['grid'] as $color => $sizes)
    <tr>
        <td colspan="{{count($sizes)+1}}">
            {{$color}}
        </td>
        <?php $totals = 0 ?>
        @foreach ($sizes as $size)
        <td>
            {{ $size['description'] }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php $totals += $size['total']  ?>
            {{ $size['total'] }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        @endforeach
        <td>TOTAL</td>
        <td>{{$totals}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that :

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    <table class="pack-table">
        <tr>
            <th width="30%">Color</th>
            <th width="10%">Pack</th>
            <th width="60%">Total Units</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($item['grid'] as $color => $sizes)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $color }}</td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                    <?php $total = 0; ?>
                    @foreach ($sizes as $size)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $size['description'] }}</td>
                        <tr>
                        <?php $total += $size['total'] ?>
                    @endforeach
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>{{ $total }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        
    </table>
@endforeach
```